# REIL Implementations and Adoption?

Tags: static-analysis, reil

Apart from [BinNavi](http://www.zynamics.com/binnavi.html) (A commercial product from the creators of [REIL](http://www.zynamics.com/downloads/csw09.pdf)), I am only aware of one project using REIL, which [implements a tiny handful](https://github.com/lightbulbone/ICE/blob/master/translator/x86_reil/x86.py) (mov/add/sub/inc/jmp) of the translators to convert x86 to REIL.

What other 3rd party REIL implementations are currently public?

Further more, are there any public works using REIL for static analysis? (Either requiring BinNavi or another product which produces REIL output).

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about public tool support, but Axel Simon's research group has put out some work describing how they extended REIL:  http://www2.in.tum.de/bib/files/sepp11precise.pdf

Answer (score 1):

REIL is implemented with ANTLR (to my knowledge). However I never saw the OpenSource release of the Lexer/Parser.